# Runtime Exception in Android JUnit testing

Tags: android, exception, junit, android-activity, android-intent

I have a simple HelloWorld Activity that I try to test with an Android JUnit test. The application itself runs like it should but the test fails with an

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN flags=0x10000000 comp={no.helloworld.HelloWorld/no.helloworld.HelloWorld} }
at no.helloworld.test.HelloWorldTestcase.setUp(HelloWorldTestcase.java:21)"

This is my activity class:

> package no.helloworld;
>
> import android.app.Activity; import
>
> android.os.Bundle;
>
> public class HelloWorld extends
>   Activity {
>
> @Override
>
> ```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
> } }
> ```

And the test:

> public class HelloWorldTestcase extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
>
> ```
> private HelloWorld myActivity;
> private TextView mView;
> private String resourceString;
> ```

```
public HelloWorldTestcase() {
    super("no.helloworld.HelloWorld", HelloWorld.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    myActivity = this.getActivity();
    mView = (TextView) myActivity.findViewById(no.helloworld.R.id.txt1);
    resourceString = myActivity
            .getString(no.helloworld.R.string.helloworld);
}

public void testPreconditions() {
    assertNotNull(mView);
}

public void testText() {
    assertEquals(resourceString, (String) mView.getText());
}

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}
```

Why does the test fail? The activity is (of course) defined in AndroidManifest.xml and the application runs as it should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package in the constructor call should match the instrumentation target in the manifest. It should be "no.helloworld" instead of "no.helloworld.HelloWorld"

Comment: "The package in the constructor call should match the instrumentation target in the manifest" - This helped me. I spent some hours with this problem.